# Not all elements change font

Tags: table-of-contents, footnotes, page-numbering, sans-serif

I am creating a document which needs to be in Sans Serif font.  I have used the \sffamily command at the beginning of the body, which changes the font of the body, no problem.  I have also used \allsectionsfont{\sffamily} which has changed the font in section headings.

I am now left with the following which are still in the standard serif font:

- Page numbers
- ToC Page numbers for subsections and lower
- Footnote markers and text

Is anyone able to help with commands to change the above to sans serif font as well?

Many thanks!

Comment: `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}` should work for everything.